# Rails: uglifier gem won't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, uglifier

I am getting an error when trying to load server and migrate databases in rails. 
My uglifier gem wont load and i need it to run devise properly.

This is the error i get:

```
 There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
```

I am running windows 8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have nodejs installed? If not, you can run `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

P.S. you can do `node -v` to see if you have nodejs installed.